# Issue with code to check for empty input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I found this tutorial to create an email form to send emails however there seems to be an error within the java script code which can be found below:

```
$('#sendfeedback').on("click", function() {
var url = 'api/send.php';
var error = 0;
var $contactpage = $(this).closest('.ui-page');
var $contactform = $(this).closest('.contact-form');
$('.required', $contactform).each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        error++;
    } 
}); // each
if (error > 0) {
        alert('Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk *.'); } 
else {//some code}
```

The click works fine but even if the fields are populated the error shows up how can I stop this from happening? Note that when I remove this part of the code it works. Below is the HTML code:

```
<div class="contact-thankyou" style="display: none;">
                Thank you.  Your message has been sent.  We will get back to you as soon as we can.
            </div>
            <div class="contact-form">
                <p class="mandatory">All fields are Manadatory</p>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="senderName">Your Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" class="required">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="senderEmail">Your Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" class="required">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="subjectCategories">Subject</label>
                        <select name="subjectCategories" id="subjectCategories" data-native-menu="false" class="required">
                            <option value="" data-placeholder="true">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Registration">Register as an Artist</option>
                            <option value="Feature">Want your music featured?</option>
                            <option value="Advertising">Advertise your company</option>
                            <option value="App Issues">App Issues</option>
                            <option value="General Feedback">General Feedback</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message" class="required" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                    </div>
                <div class="send"><a href="javascript:;" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" id="sendfeedback">Send Feedback</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: use of jquery .live() is no longer recommended, recommend using .on() as it has none of the drawbacks of .live()

Comment: ok will make that change however that isnt the error though as the error has to do with mandatory fields even when they are filled am still getting the error

Comment: i don't see any problem. if `*` marked fields are filled with data you don't get any error prompt as such. [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7CDV/)

Comment: this is strange I am going to edit the html which I have now and then tell me if there is any issue with it because it seems the same to me @phobos

Comment: I changed the html are there any errors you can spot? @phobos

Comment: Validations are good. No error when fields are filled up. [another demo with changed html](http://jsfiddle.net/AEKjC/) sorry, there's no id mismatch. I might have referenced old js code

Comment: @phobos so am good to go then? Strange as this same code wasnt working yesterday thanks for the help

Comment: last question my `.on` is not firing but when i change it to `.live` it works am using jquery 1.8.2

Comment: `.on()` was added in `1.7`. It should work.

Comment: @phobos no its not firing unless I use live I am pulling it from an external js file would that make a difference

Comment: Make sure it doesn't fire twice.

Comment: I changed it to `$(document).on('click', '#sendfeedback', function () {`and that works but the code still doesn't work for me

Comment: You error is in `select menu`, i'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you want to validate four fields with class `required`. On `#subjectCategories` select menu, the class `required` is being added twice, one for `<select>` popup menu, and the other one is added to a `<span>` under `<a>` which calls the select menu `#subjectCategories`. The `span` has no value and it caused the error.

I made an easy fix by adding the below code, right after triggering the validation, to remove the extra `required` class from the `span`.

```
$('#sendfeedback').on("click", function () {
 $($.mobile.activePage).find('span').removeClass('required');
 //....
 //the rest of your code
 //...
});
```

Comment: this works, i have no idea how you saw that other required class but am not seeing it in my code is jquery creating that when the code is launched in the browser? If not I would like a cleaner way to remove it if possible.

Comment: I used Chrome to debug the code (f12). JQM adds the extra class to the `span` automatically. I'm not sure whether there's a cleaner way to remove it, however, you can be more specific by using `.contact-form` instead of `$.mobile.activePage`. Anyway, it will only find `span` with `required` class, it wouldn't affect other elements.